# Java - How to read an excel when it is already open (Which is opened by clicking open button in a web application)?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have an application where I have a button and when I click on it, it will provide me two options to save or open an excel report.

When I save it I can read the data from the downloads folder for the excel downloaded using APACHE POI.

But when I click on Open button and open the excel, is there any way to read data from the opened excel.(I need to verify the data in the excel).

Thank you,
Subbu.

Answer (score 1):

While the file is open in Excel it is locked, so the same file cannot be opened by any other program.

This behaviour is by design, it is built into Windows and there is no way around it.

What you can do is to make a copy, then open one copy in Excel and other in your Java program.

Alternatively, you could try to find a way to open the file in shared read-only mode - this is permitted, but the read-only mode has to be requested by both Excel and your Java program.